# MERCADOPAGO CHECKOUT PRO MEDIOS DE PAGO

Tags: javascript, php, mercadopago

Mi problema es el siguiente. Dentro de los pasos del checkout del proyecto se pueden elegir los medios de pago. Los pagos en tarjeta de credito y debito se hacen mediante checkout API, y los medios de pago de saldo en cuenta o efectivo se hacen mediante PRO. Mi necesidad actual es que al seleccionar que abona con saldo en cuenta se excluya el resto de los medios de pago, y lo mismo con el pago en efectivo. Ya se como excluir los pagos pero intento hacerlo con javascript checked y no logro hacerlo obviamente porque el array es con php. Desde ya muchas gracias!
[image: Imagen de pasarela]

PROBLEMA MAS PUNTUAL => Al seleccionar las opciones que son en metodo PRO. Debe cambiar las preferencias del checkout. Por ejemplo, si yo tengo chequeado "saldo en cuenta" que en el modal unicamente aparezca esa y no otras.

Comment: te doy una pista: al hacer click (evento) en una opción y esta sea *seleccionada* puedes deshabilitar. las otras que no lo están. cualquier cosa puede preguntar en los soporte de PRO y Mercado pago...

Comment: El problema es que al hacer click no puedo hacer que se modifique el array de php ya que es un evento por parte de javascript. O si podria hacerlo?

Comment: esa es la parte donde tienes que investigar ...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si, estoy investigando y creo que lo intentare con Fetch. Que opinas?

Comment: puedes usar el método que mejor te lo facilite...

Comment: Ya logre con Fetch Api distinguir entre los radio seleccionados. Ahora, deberia crear una variable de sesion o similar para insertar el array verdad?